# GraphQL Inline fragments check if exist and then output in a .map

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have a react component in gatsbyJS that is mapping through a graphQL query, so far it works however I have introduced a inline fragment in the graphQL query two of them actually and I want to check if fragment exists then output the code otherwise all my maps are outputting empty div's after real content is outputted. I didn't include the whole query or all the code for brevity.

Hopefully someone can help, Thanks!

Here is my map and jsx

```
{data.datoCmsProject.projectBlock.map(projectEntry => { 

        return (  

          <>

          // I want to check here if    DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid fragment exists then render below       

          <BlockGridWrapper>
            <BlockGrid key={projectEntry.id}>

                <div>{projectEntry.titleOfGridSection}</div>
            </BlockGrid>
          </BlockGridWrapper>

        // end check for DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid

        // I want to check here if DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent fragment exists, then render below

         <NewBlock key={projectEntry.id}> 

          <img key={imageEntry.originalId} src={imageEntry.url}/>

         </NewBlock>

        //end check for DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent

...
```

Here is my query

```
projectBlock{
        ... on DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent {
            id
            titleOfSection
            descriptionOfImage
            descriptionToggle
            wideView
            imageTextSide
            imageAssetHideShow
            imageAsset{
              url
              originalId
            }
          }
        ... on DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid {
          id
          titleOfGridSection
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `__typename` field to determine the type of the returned object and then render the appropriate component.

```
projectBlock {
  __typename
  ... on DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent {
    id
    # other fields
  }
  ... on DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid {
    id
    # other fields
  }
}
```

In this case, `__typename` will resolve to `DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent`, `DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid` or whatever other possible types for the `projectBlock` field. If there are other possible types that you don't want to render, you should either filter the array first or utilize `reduce` instead of `map` to the same effect:

```
data.datoCmsProject.projectBlock
  .filter(({ __typename }) => __typename === 'DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent' || __typename === 'DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid')
  .map(projectEntry => {
  if (projectEntry.__typename === 'DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent') {
    return <BlockGridWrapper/>
  }
  return <NewBlock/>
})
```